# Facebook data extraction

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

Can we extract/read the posts and comments from **groups**, which I am not owning on Facebook using **Facebook4j** or by some other API or method?

Answer (score 0):

- Check if group's privacy setting is OPEN.
- Using [getGroupFeed(String groupId)](http://facebook4j.org/javadoc/facebook4j/api/GroupMethods.html#getGroupFeed(java.lang.String)), you could get the group's wall.
- Once you are aware of groupId and that particular group is OPEN, I guess you could extract posts from that group.
- Please check Facebook4j's documentation : [Groups Interface in Facebook4j](http://facebook4j.org/javadoc/facebook4j/api/GroupMethods.html)
- Also, check Reference docs in Facebook developers regarding access token for groups [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#groups).
  Hope it helps